# I have four files with 10 lines of each, how to get output like below

Tags: shell-script, scripting, perl

I have 4 files. I need to check that all the files have equal number of lines.

If the numbers of lines differ, I need to detect this and output, for example:

```
#file1 - 10 lines, file2 - 9 lines, file3 - 10 lines, file4 - 10 lines
Line are miss matched
Number of lines 10 = 9 = 10 = 10
```

If they are equal, I want to merge the files line by line as follows:

**Files:**

```
#file1
10 
12
11

#file2
Arun
kamal
babu

#file3
300
200
400

#file4
spot1
spot4
spot5
```

**Output:**

```
Set1
10
Arun
300
spot1

Set2
12
kamal
200
spot4

Set3
11
babu
400
spot5
```

**My code:**

```
#

id_name=`cat file2`
echo $id_name

id_list=`cat file1`
echo $id_list

#

id_count=`cat file3`
echo $id_count

id_spot=`cat spot_list`
echo $id_spot


SS=`cat id_list | wc -l`
DS=`cat id_name | wc -l`
SF=`cat id_count | wc -l`
DF=`cat id_spot | wc -l`

if [ $SS == $DS == $SF == $DF ] then

   echo " Line are matched"
   echo " Total line $SS"


   for i j in $id_list $id_name
   do
      for a b in $id_count $id_spot
      do
         k = 1
         echo " Set$k"
         $i
         $j
         $a
         $b
      done
   done

else

   echo " Line are Miss matched"
   echo " Total line $SS  = $DS = $SF = $DF"

fi
```

Comment: Try formatting your code in question following my example.

Comment: is this your school assignment? Did you try already something? Can you show us Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? Also can you tell us what language you need this to be in because I would automatically go for bash, but you have perl in the tags so I don't know if it's a requirment.

Comment: None of the lines in your files match and your output shows information that isn't in any of the input files. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need to do.

Comment: @Vlastimil  pls check now

Comment: @Ordoshsen pls check now

Comment: @terdon please check now

Comment: SO you're talking about the number of lines? You just want to check if all files have the same number of lines? And if they don't, what should be printed? How can we know which line is missing? Or added? And what are all these "sets" you output? Please [edit] this, and give us a simple example where we can understand why ever line is shown. Use 2-3 lines, not 10 so we can understand more easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a really straightforward approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SS=$(wc -l < file1)
DS=$(wc -l < file2)
SF=$(wc -l < file3)
DF=$(wc -l < file4)


if [[ $SS -eq $DS && $DS -eq $SF && $SF -eq $DF ]]; then 
   echo "Lines are matched"
   echo "Total number of lines: $SS"

   num=1
   while (( num <= SS )); do
      echo "Set$num"
      tail -n +$num file1 | head -n 1
      tail -n +$num file2 | head -n 1
      tail -n +$num file3 | head -n 1
      tail -n +$num file4 | head -n 1

      ((num++))
      echo
   done

else
   echo "Line are miss matched"
   echo "Number of lines $SS = $DS = $SF = $DF"
fi
```

It is not very efficient as it calls `tail` 4*number_of_lines times but it is straightforward.

---

Another approach is to replace the `while` loop with `awk`:

```
awk '{
   printf("\nSet%s\n", NR)
   print; 
   if( getline < "file2" )
      print
   if( getline < "file3" )
      print
   if ( getline < "file4" )
      print
}' file1
```

---

To join files line by line, the `paste` command is very useful. You can use this instead of the `while` loop:

```
paste -d$'\n' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Or maybe a little less obvious:

```
{ cat -n file1 ; cat -n file2 ; cat -n file3; cat -n file4; }  | sort -n  | cut -f2-
```

That will output the lines but with no formatting (no Set1, Set2, newlines, ...), so you have to format it afterwards with `awk`, for example:

```
awk '{ 
   if ((NR-1)%4 == 0) 
      printf("\nSet%s\n", (NR+3)/4) 
   print 
}' < <(paste -d$'\n' file1 file2 file3 file4)
```

---

Some final notes:

- Do not use uppercase variables as they could collide with environment and internal shell variables
- Do not use `echo "$var" | cmd` or `cat file | cmd` when you can redirect input: `cmd <<< "$var"` or `cmd < file`
- You can have only one variable name in `for` loop. `for i in ...` is valid, whereas `for i j in ...` is not
- It is better to use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` for testing, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash)
- There are a **lot** of ways to do this
- It's up to you which approach you choose to use but be aware of the efficiency differences:

Results of `time`, tested on files with 10000 lines:

```
#first approach
real    0m45.387s
user    0m5.904s
sys     0m3.836s
```

```
#second approach - significantly faster
real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.040s
```

```
#third approach - very close to second approach
real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.036s
```

Answer (score 5):

You can figure out how to check the number of lines for each file (hint: `wc`)

To get your output of sets:

```
paste File{1,2,3,4} | awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1; print "Set"NR, $0, ""}'
```

`$1=$1` is used to convert the input field separators to output field separators.

Comment: Nice! `$1=$1` is a nice trick. I was trying to figure out some overly complicated solutions and this didn't even occur to me...

Comment: There is also `tr '\t' '\n'` but the doesn't give you the headers